# Getting permission denied when pushing to git vps server

Tags: windows, ssh

I installed git for windows, creating my ssh key and uploaded the public to my server.

I have this working on my Mac, trying to get it working on my windows machine now.

I did a :

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh/
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
```

Here is an image of me doing a ssh -v gitserveralias

I have a config file that has the gitserveralias and port etc.

[image]

I tried clearing out the known hosts file also.

My config looks like:

```
Host serveralias
       User xxx
       Hostname 123.234.452.232
       Port 22222
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
       TCPKeepAlive true
       IdentitiesOnly yes
       PreferredAuthentications publickey
```

Again I have my setup working fine on my Mac.

Comment: It doesn't seem to ask for my passphrase, could that be something?

Comment: Did you copy your private key (generated on Mac?) to the windows machine?

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check:

1. Do you have "PubkeyAuthentication yes" in sshd_config on your server? Try setting it.
2. Is there an offending key in .ssh/known_hosts? Try removing this file.

Comment: I tried deleting known_hosts, no change.  i'll check the sshd_config.